# flowplayer with rssfeeds

Tags: php, javascript

I have rssfeed website on which I have put some video/audio podcasts .
How can I embedded flowplayer so that it can show small icon for video to play with each link of podcast rssfeed.
If any one know this Please help me.
Regards,
lnj.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use jQuery to read in the RSS feed using $.ajax, loop through each item in the feed and append Flowplayer to the HTML page.

Using jQuery to read RSS:
http://www.reindel.com/five_javascript_tricks_jquery/ (scroll to bottom)

Flowplayer has a jQuery API:
http://flowplayer.org/documentation/api/index.html

Hope that helps